# Terraform vm_name_prefix auto increment modification

Tags: terraform

I have been strugling to find anything useful on google so here I am.

We are currently working on the deployment of 2 new VMs.

We are using https://github.com/vancluever/terraform-vsphere-virtual-machine

In the Terraform tfvars we have these two attributes:

```
vm_count = "2"
vm_name_prefix = "something000"
```

Now after running the dry run Terraform will name the VMs

```
name:    something0000
name:    something0001
```

But we want the name of the VMs to start with "1" and count up from there.

```
name:    something0001
name:    something0002
```

Is there a way to get this behavior from Terraform?

I seem to have found the code which defines this behavior:
(vsphere_virutal_machine_linux.tf)

```
resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "virtual_machine_linux" {
  count            = "${var.template_os_family == "linux" ? var.vm_count : 0}"
  name             = "${var.vm_name_prefix}${count.index}"
  resource_pool_id = "${data.vsphere_resource_pool.pool.id}"
  datastore_id     = "${data.vsphere_datastore.ds.id}"

  num_cpus = "${var.num_cpus}"
  memory   = "${var.memory}"
  guest_id = "${data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.guest_id}"

  wait_for_guest_net_timeout = "${var.wait_for_guest_net_timeout}"

  network_interface {
    network_id = "${data.vsphere_network.network.id}"
}
```

Can we overwrite this definition without having to download and modify the git repo?

Comment: Can you share your code that is actually creating the VMs and thus the names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/interpolation.html#math) is probably what you're looking for. All you should need is a simple `+ 1`

```
name = "${var.vm_name_prefix}${count.index + 1}"
```

Answer (score 4):

While [SteveGoob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3289080/stevegoob)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55511662/2291321) solves the fact that Terraform (like all good programming languages) uses 0 indexing while humans are big fans of 1 indexing your static prefix with leading 0s is nonsensical.

If you have 9 machines you'll have the names `something0001` through to `something0009`. But on the 10th machine you'll end up with `something00010`. Note that you still have the same amount of leading zeros.

Instead you can use the fact that Terraform allows for printf style formatting:

```
name = "${var.vm_name_prefix}${format("%0000d", count.index + 1)}"
```

This will mean that if you have 9 machines you'll have the names `something0001` through to `something0009`. But on the 10th machine you'll end up with `something0010` and on the 9999th machine it will be `something9999`.

Answer (score 0):

Even though your shared TF code does not seem to be HCL I think the solution to your problem is to have an external variable that has a starting value of 1 and you increment it in every iteration step.

```
name_index = [1, 2, 3, 4]

resource "example" "name" {
  count = 4
  name = "${var.name_index[count.index]}"
}
```